# android set android drawable for color

Tags: android

I create a drawable.xml for some purpose , and i want to use this color:#29395e.

But i can't set up the #29395e in android:drawable .

I try to use `<item android:color=" #29395e"/>` , it can't compile.

Is any way i can use this color #29395e in this drawable ?

Any help will be grateful.

here is my drawable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/corner_with_tab" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: you can use this in your colors.xml file...
<color name="colorName">#29395e</color>
and use that color into your drawable file

Comment: LOL i gave first solution...):

Comment: Sorry man , i miss it , thanks for your help , truely

Comment: well, but i gave you answer in comment.and no sorry man.because no one can give vote up for comment.

Comment: also i was not sure about my answer.if it is true or false. that is why i did comment...(:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make a "colors.xml" resource file in res/values folder

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorName">#4da6ff</color>
</resources>
```

now in your mydrawable file use that color like this

```
 <item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@color/colorName" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating a new xml file, you can just add this and it will work as well.

```xml
   <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#18191B" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

So your entire code will be

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/corner_with_tab" android:state_selected="true" />
       <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#18191B" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

if your `drawable.xml`  is right then

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/corner_with_tab" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
</selector>
```

Create **drawable** **colors.xml**  under **`values`** folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="corner_with_tab">#3F51B5</color> // Example. Add your Hex color

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

1、Edit a xml file such as `abc.xml` in your drawable folder.
2、`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="#29395e" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="#29395e" />
</selector>`
3、In your layout.xml,use `android:src="@drawable/abc"`

Answer (score 0):

adding color with xml is

```
<item android: android:color="@color/new_color" />

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/corner_with_tab" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:color="@color/holo_blue_light"/>
```

Comment: so the color will take if the state is not selected and not pressed